# Name two distinct bases of a set

Tags: vector-spaces

Given are the vectors (in $\mathbb{R^5}$):

$$v_1 = (0, 1, 0, 2, 0), v_2 = (0, -1, -3, -2, 0), v_3 = (0, 0, 1, 0, 0)$$

I'm suppossed to name two different bases for $L(v_1, v_2, v_2)$.

I know that one base is $B_1 = \{(0, 1, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1, 0)\}$, but I'm not quiet sure how to figure out further bases of the set. The three vectors in $L$ are linearly dependant.

As far as I can remember there is an infinite amount of bases for a given set, but I don't quiet understand how you should figure them out. I'm probably missing something important here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This is the second time you ask the same question. What kind of answer are you wishing?

Comment: @mfl It's not the same question per se, I realised that the first one was actually fairly easy to solve since all vectors were linearly independent (which meant that I had 2 more or less trivial solutions lying in front of me and could generate more solutions by using linear combinations of the three vectors as vectors of the basis), but in this case I can neither use the vectors of $L$ as solution (since they aren't linearly independent) and can also not generate more solutions by using linear combinations of the vectors (since they are, again, linearly dependent).

Comment: @LouisB Yep, that's a solution, and thanks to the answer posted below I know actually know how to come up general solutions. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find out first how many independent vectors you have (only 2 since $v_2=-1\cdot v_1-3\cdot v_3$). So your basis of $L$ must contain exactly two vectors. You can choose $(v_1, v_2)$ or $(v_1, v_3)$ or $(v_2, v_3)$ or any linear combination $(a v_1+b v_2+c v_3,d v_1+e v_2+f v_3)$ as long as $a v_1+b v_2+c v_3\ne(d v_1+e v_2+f v_3)\cdot r$, where $r$ is a real number

Comment: Thank you, this finally explains how all of this actually works to me!

Comment: Just one more clarification: the basis is the minimum number of vectors to describe your $L$, and any combination of the basis vectors must be in $L$. So for your initial guess you can have $(0,1,0,1,0)$ created from your vectors, but it's not in $L$

Comment: I figured something along those lines out while guessing combinations as well, but couldn't quiet make sense of why some combinations should be generating systems why others shouldn't be. This helped me a ton with my understanding of the topic, thank you very much!